# geospatial data points outside of polygon after using a "contains" predicate using "GeoDataFrame.sjoin"

Tags: visualization, geospatial, geopandas, folium

I am visualizing data points from an Uber drives in New South Wales of Australia dataset on a Folium map, but some of the data points were inside the sea instead of being on the mainland, I tried using a polygon data set of the New South Wales of Australia so that I can use `GeoDataFrame.sjoin` on both data sets with the "contains" predicate, however, some of the points are still outside, how can I solve this?

This is my code

```
geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.pick_up_lon, df.pick_up_lat), crs="EPSG:4326")
poly_df = gpd.read_file("state.geojson")
join_df = gpd.sjoin(poly_df, geo_df, predicate="contains")
```

[before applying the polygon]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yF82.jpg

[after applying the polygon and the sjoin, you can still see points outside the polygon in the sea]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6FgR.jpg

Answer (score 2):

The operation you want is `clip()` Clip the points so you only have points within your required boundary.  Code below shows this structured in similar way to your code.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# get some geojson for NSW
poly_df = (
    gpd.read_file(
        "https://github.com/tonywr71/GeoJson-Data/raw/master/suburb-2-nsw.geojson"
    )
    .dissolve()
    .loc[:, ["geometry"]]
)

# some of these points will be in the sea....
r = np.random.RandomState(22)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "pick_up_lon": r.choice(np.linspace(*poly_df.total_bounds[[0, 2]], 100), 30),
        "pick_up_lat": r.choice(np.linspace(*poly_df.total_bounds[[1, 3]], 100), 30),
    }
)

geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.pick_up_lon, df.pick_up_lat), crs="EPSG:4326"
)

# remove points outside NSW
geo_df.clip(poly_df).explore()
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it once I return to that project in the future, I kinda lost hope in the middle of it and started another project.